# Is there a way to make .NET MF 4.3 RTM (QFE1) work on Visual Studio 2013 or 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-micro-framework

I am using STM32F429I-Discovery. Currently I have the latest NETMF (4.3.2) installed. There nothing goes wrong until deployment. When I try to deploy I get the error about that device(development board) has **mscorlib 4.3.0.0** whereas I am trying to deploy **mscorlib 4.3.1.0**.

I thought that the solution would be to use a previous release of NETMF SDK. When I tried to install it it tells me this sdk requires Visual Studio 2012. I already have 2013 and 2015. So is there a workaround or a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed solution of installing a previous release is correct. Obviously, the mscorlib versions have to match.

The installaltion process of NETMF SDK needs a version of Visual Studio 2012. The express version is fine ([VS2012 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34673)).

For your development and deployment of your software you can use any version of VisualStudio.

Comment: That's interesting. So I can install VS2012 but can develop on 2015?

Comment: Yes, VS 2012 is only needed for the installation of NETMF.

Comment: Quick suggestion. Even though you can develop application on 2015, class libraries that are built by 2015 causes problem (No error, no message. It just doesn't work). For class libraries we still need to built with 2012.